# ¿Porque mi tabla generada por html generic en c# me lo poner como texto y no como elemento html?

Tags: c#, html5

Actualmente quiero generar unas cuantas filas en una tabla dependiendo de las imágenes que tenga almacenadas en una ubicación, solo que cuando quiero concatenar todo con un `innerhtml` me lo genera como texto la estructura de la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve en el inspector  de elementos del navegador

Código de la tabla:

```
public void btnOk_T_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


             DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Ned-Design\Documents\projects\NederaV4\Administrators\Temp");//Assuming Test is your Folder
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.png"); //Getting Text files
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("TABLE");
            createDiv.ID = "createTable";
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {

                //createDiv.ID = "createDivM";
                //createDiv.InnerHtml = " <img src=Temp" + "\\" + file.Name + " style='width:100%;margin-top:2%'> ";
                //this.Controls.Add(createDiv);
                //createDiv.Attributes["class"] = "col-md-4";

                createDiv.InnerHtml +="<tr>< td ></ td >< td ></ td >< td ></ td >< td ></ td >< td ></ td > < td ></ td ></ tr >";

                conta++;
            }
            this.Controls.Add(createDiv);
        }
```

Comment: trata de usar htmlContainerControl en lugar de genericcontrol

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza esto, sera mejor, tambien funciona para JavaScript:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "render", "el html aqui");
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte! Para mantener la calidad del sitio te sugiero basar tus respuestas en: [answer]